# Fixed width text rendering in pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm working on a display in Python 2.7.10 using pygame to render the text. I would like a clock centered at the top of the main display, and I can get it to display correctly. However, when the width of the time shrinks (Such as a 1 displayed instead of a 2) it shifts the position slightly.

Here is the rendering portion:

```
def drawText(string, x, y, font):
    if font == "readout":
        text = readoutFont.render(string, True, GREEN)
        {...}
    elif font == "gen":
        text = genFont.render(string, True, LT_BLUE)
    elif font == "clockFont":
        text = clockFont.render(string, True, LT_BLUE)


textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx + x
textRect.centery = windowSurface.get_rect().centery + y
windowSurface.blit(text, textRect)
```

And here is the time calling the drawtext routine:

```
    currentDate = datetime.date.today()
    currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()

    drawText(currentDate.strftime("%b %d %Y"), 0, -220, "clockFont")
    drawText(currentTime.strftime("%H %M %S"), 0, -200, "clockFont")
```

How can I create the time at a fixed point/width so that it doesn't shift slightly as the text width changes?

Comment: What are `x` and `y`? Please [edit] your code to make a [mre]. Or you could centre the text more simply `windowSurface.blit(text, text.get_rect(center=windowSurface.get_rect().center))`

Comment: @importrandom - Done. X and Y are passed in variables for offset from center of the screen.

Comment: It's okay to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I stated in my question without realizing it at first.

The routine in the question is designed to find the center of the screen and offset the text from there in order to line everything up from center. Since the clock changes widths, it would move slightly when the width of the time changed.

I changed the above routine to be as follows and just draw the time at a fixed point.

```
if font != "clockFont":
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx + x
    textRect.centery = windowSurface.get_rect().centery + y
    windowSurface.blit(text, textRect)
else:
    windowSurface.blit(text, (304, 30))
```